# Is this function periodic function?

Tags: periodic-functions

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational number and $0$ if $x$ is irrational number. Is $f$ a periodic function.

A hour ago, in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410647/non-periodic-function-with-infinite-roots?noredirect=1#comment4977112_2410647), I said that this function is not periodic, then **Kenny Lau** told that I am wrong. He also said that "well, any rational number is a period... $f(x+r)=f(x)$ if $r\in\mathbb{Q}$".

Now, I am totally confused about periodic functions. It means there must infinitely many periods.

It would be very helpful if someone explain it elaborately.

Comment: One approach (as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1704020/81360)) is to assert that such an $f$ is "periodic, but with undefined fundamental period".

Comment: But if the function is periodic, not constant and has at least one point where it is continuous, there is a minimal period, and every period is a multiple of that minimal period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A periodic function doesn't necessarily have a minimal period. As long as it repeats itself ($\exists c>0: \forall x \in \Bbb R: f(x+c) = f(x)$), then it is periodic.

Comment: Ah! thanks! for example $f(x)=1$ is also periodic.

Comment: @MANMAID precisely.